# How to fill color in an imagemap in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is the code:-
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Observers Dashboard hhttps://xd.adobe.com/view/d532ccdf-7a7a-4d1e-a819-5ce157cdbded-8061/screen/a779cae4-5263-465f-a743-e5c8caf68b0a  -->
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
```

'''
[This is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaG14.png)

I have to fill color in different districts of the image map, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @shrcod - this question is still open. If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Comment: Hi @shrcod - Did the below answer solve your question? If so, please mark it with the checkmark to close out the question. Otherwise, please update your question (or post a comment below the answer) to help us fine-tune our assistance. Or, please post your own answer to show how you solved the problem and checkmark that answer, again, to close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest/easiest way to do this is with the [ImageMapster jQuery plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) by James Treworgy.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

These demos show that it will do exactly what you desire:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

By calling `$('img').mapster(options)`, ImageMapster will attempt to bind to each image that has an associated map. An area within the image map can be selected with `$('area').mapster('select')`. The project has lots of options and features.

Here is code for a somewhat basic example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/